# Handling a set of FORM errors with ONE foreach loop?

Tags: php, forms, foreach

I have a stack of 'Select' menus / dropdowns on a PHP form on my website.

I'd like to **check an option on each menu has been selected before processing** the rest of the form, and wondered if I could loop through all of the fields with PHP?

Started with something like the following, but got a bit lost:

```
        foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
        //$errormsg.= $key." - ".$val."\n";

             if ($_POST['FIELD_NAME_HERE']){            
                     $FIELD_NAME_HERE_field = $_POST['FIELD_NAME_HERE'];
             } else {
                     $errormsg.= "<li>Please select from the FIELD_NAME_HERE options</li>";
             }

        }
```

Is this possible? And if so, how do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
//$errormsg.= $key." - ".$val."\n";

    if ($val)
    {            
        ${$key.'_field'} = $val;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $errormsg.= "<li>Please select from the $key options</li>";
    }
}
```

It's probably not how I would have approached handling form errors though.

Comment: It seems this `${$key}_field = $val;` bit is giving me an error.

Comment: Out of interest, how would you handle it different to mine? Totally open to ideas here. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Wooooooooooop!!! It works :-D
Guess I wasn't too far off then. 

Many thanks Fluffeh!!!!

Comment: @mcgarriers Okay, try that syntax - it's not giving me any errors in either eclipse or when I run the code (not testing it with post data though). I would be focusing on doing all the verification that I could before the form was submitted - then checking each one individually - and if needed outputting a seperate error message for each problem. Having said that, I have never had to use a form with loads of individual elements.

Comment: I've got some jQuery processing the form but this is a really good fallback should the JS fail/user disabled JS.